# Вывод русских символов из pd.Timestamp().month_name()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

В атрибуте `month_name()` объекта `Timestamp` есть аргумент `locale=None`, где `None` по умолчанию означает английский. 
При заведении значения аргумента `Russian` выдается непонятный шифр. Код и результаты ниже:

```
d = pd.to_datetime('12.12.12')
print(d.month_name(locale='Russian'))

>>> Äåêàáðü
```

Работа в Jupyter Notebook. Какие предустановки надо сделать, чтобы решить проблему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо установить правильную `locale`:

```
import sys
import locale

def set_rus_locale():
    locale.setlocale(
        locale.LC_ALL,
        'rus_rus' if sys.platform == 'win32' else 'ru_RU.UTF-8')
```

---

Примеры:

```
In [4]: d = pd.to_datetime(['12.12.12','12.01.12','12.03.12','12.05.12'], dayfirst=True)
```

`locale` по умолчанию:

```
In [5]: d.month_name(locale='Russian')
Out[5]: Index(['Äåêàáðü', 'SSíâàðü', 'Ìàðò', 'Ìàé'], dtype='object')
```

`locale='Russian'`:

```
In [6]: set_rus_locale()

In [7]: d.month_name(locale='Russian')
Out[7]: Index(['Декабрь', 'Январь', 'Март', 'Май'], dtype='object')
```